# Searching sub-form, data mismatch error

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm using Access 2007.

I have a txt box that filters a subform called fsGetRFIDOwnership.

The code i'm using is below in afterupdate of txtbox.

Me.fsGetRFIDOwnership.Form.Filter = "RFID = '" & Me.txtSearch & "' OR Country = '" & Me.txtSearch & "' OR BuildingName = '" & Me.txtSearch & "' OR RFIDType = '" & Me.txtSearch & "'"

The problem i'm having that this worked all fine until i added the search by RFID as well, RFID is an autonumber. And now i just get a data mismatch error. The other fields are text. What exactly is going wrong here and how can i fix it? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Cheers tchadwik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use quotes for numeric fields:

```
Me.fsGetRFIDOwnership.Form.Filter = "RFID = " & Me.txtSearch _
& " OR Country = '" & Me.txtSearch & "' OR BuildingName = '" _
& Me.txtSearch & "' OR RFIDType = '" & Me.txtSearch & "'"
```

Edit

```
sCriteria = "Cstr(RFID) = '" & Me.txtSearch _
& "' OR Country = '" & Me.txtSearch & "' OR BuildingName = '" _
& Me.txtSearch & "' OR RFIDType = '" & Me.txtSearch & "'"

If DCount("ID","MyTable", sCriteria)>0 Then
    Me.fsGetRFIDOwnership.Form.Filter = sCriteria
    Me.fsGetRFIDOwnership.Form.FilterOn = True
End If
```

Comment: I then get another problem which is whenever i enter a text search that doesn't find a match a enter parameter value window pops up.

Comment: First check for a match, then apply the filter.

Comment: Thanks for your help Remou, but now having problems with DCount. The following is the code i'm using where qRFIDOwnerQuery is the same source that the subform uses. It works if I put in a number in but when text is entered it gives me a runtime error.                     If DCount("RFID","qRFIDOwnerQuery", sCriteria)>0 Then
    Me.fsGetRFIDOwnership.Form.Filter = sCriteria
    Me.fsGetRFIDOwnership.Form.FilterOn = True
End If

Comment: My last comment did not appear the way i wanted it to.

Comment: No problem. I see what you are at. You need to convert the ID to a string, the count will still be useful enough, but you will not *have* to have it. `"Cstr(RFID) = '" & Me.txtSearch & "'`